# AttributeError: module 'emoji' has no attribute 'get_emoji_regexp'

Tags: python, emoji

This is the code I'm using in Google Colab

```
import re 
from textblob import TextBlob 
import emoji

def clean_tweet(text): 
    text = re.sub(r'@[A-Za-z0-9]+', '', str(text)) # remove @mentions
    text = re.sub(r'#', '',  str(text)) # remove the '#' symbol
    text = re.sub(r'RT[\s]+', '',  str(text)) # remove RT
    text = re.sub(r'https?\/\/S+', '',  str(text)) # remove the hyperlink
    text = re.sub(r'http\S+', '',  str(text)) # remove the hyperlink
    text = re.sub(r'www\S+', '',  str(text)) # remove the www
    text = re.sub(r'twitter+', '',  str(text)) # remove the twitter
    text = re.sub(r'pic+', '',  str(text)) # remove the pic
    text = re.sub(r'com', '',  str(text)) # remove the com
    return text

def remove_emoji(text):
    return emoji.get_emoji_regexp().sub(u'', text)
```

When I make these calls

```
tweets['cleaned_text']=tweets['text'].apply(clean_tweet)
tweets['cleaned_text']=tweets['cleaned_text'].apply(remove_emoji)
```

I'm getting the below error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-20-9fe71f3cdb0c> in <module>
      1 tweets['cleaned_text']=tweets['text'].apply(clean_tweet)
----> 2 tweets['cleaned_text']=tweets['cleaned_text'].apply(remove_emoji)

4 frames

<ipython-input-19-8c0d6ba00a5b> in remove_emoji(text)
     24 
     25 def remove_emoji(text):
---> 26     return emoji.get_emoji_regexp().sub(u'', text)

AttributeError: module 'emoji' has no attribute 'get_emoji_regexp'
```

This is very strange. I have never seen this issue before. Could someone help me with this? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What part of the error message is unclear? Where the code says `emoji.get_emoji_regexp().sub(u'', text)`, why should this mean anything? In particular, why should the `emoji.get_emoji_regexp` part mean anything? The error message is telling you, very explicitly, that there is no `get_emoji_regexp` to be found within `emoji`. Do you think there should be? If so, why? What does the documentation say?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel this is my college project. When my profesor runs this in his local anoconda env, it is ok, but why not in colab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AttributeError: module 'emoji' has no attribute 'get_emoji_regexp'](https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji/issues/223) - `get_emoji_regexp` method was deprecated and subsequently removed in new versions of the package.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for an up-to-date solution,
`pip install demoji`,  then try this function instead:

```
def remove_emojis(text):
    return demoji.replace(text, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the current version you have and use version 1.4.1

pip install emoji==1.4.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).